# Can we do regularization by just discarding the divergent part?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, scattering, feynman-diagrams, regularization

Consider the one-loop $\phi^4$ integral to order $\lambda^2$

$$I=\int \frac{d^{4}k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{k^2-m^2}\frac{1}{(k-p)^2-m^2}.$$

After some transformation (refer to the answer in [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/436813/))

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}dx\int \frac{d^{4}l}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{(l^2+\Delta)^2},$$

where $\Delta=m^2-x(1-x)p^2$. Clearly this integral is divergent. Usually, we regularize the integral by standard regularization skills. I was wondering, can we do the regularization by discarding the divergent part of the integral? That is, we first evaluate the integral inside

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}dx \frac{1}{32\pi^2}\left(\left.\frac{\Delta}{\Delta+k^2}\right|^{\infty}_{0}+\left.\ln(\Delta+k^2)\right|^{\infty}_{0}\right)$$

Then we throw away the $\ln(\Delta+k^2)|^{\infty}$, so we obtain

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}dx\frac{1}{32\pi^2}(-1-\ln(\Delta)).$$

Is this approach possible? Since we require the scattering amplitude to be finite, it is natural to throw away the divergent part in the integral. If this approach does not work, what are the reasons?

Comment: How do you ensure without a regularization parameter that a different route of calculating a (possible more complicated) loop diagram doesn't identify a different finite piece?

Comment: I see your point, it seems that this approach doesn't work because I can't ensure the finite part is unique. But why introduce a regularization parameter can ensure the finite part is unique?